How to reduce the size of encrypted string we got from dbms crypto
Hello i have a function that encrypts a given string and output a 64 byte long i want the function to output a 16 char long not 64 here's my code
CREATE OR REPLACE function Encrypt_decrypt(input_string in VARCHAR2,Gkey varchar2,Pkey char default 'e')
return varchar2
is
--Raw Datatype used to hold unstructured binary data as the key is in hexadecimal so it's datatype must be raw
--PLS_INTEGER datatype it's the same as number datatype but it's more efficient and faster in algorithmatic operations
    output_string     VARCHAR2 (200);
--    encrypted_raw     RAW (2000);              -- stores encrypted binary text
    decrypted_raw     RAW (2000);              -- stores decrypted binary text
--    num_key_bytes     NUMBER := 256 / 8;     -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
    key_bytes_raw     RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
    encryption_type   PLS_INTEGER
        :=                                            -- total encryption type
             DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
           + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
           + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

    iv_raw            RAW (16);
BEGIN
--convert varchar2 to hexadecimal
key_bytes_raw:=RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('E@ghjk%We%g@ioy_'||Gkey||'015!5!24'));
iv_raw:=RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('AFC@_'||Gkey||'15!'));
case when lower(Pkey)='e' then  
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Original string: ' || input_string);
    --key_bytes_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (num_key_bytes);
    --iv_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (16);
    
    output_string :=
        DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT (
        --UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW convert varchar2 of encoding (AL32UTF8) to raw
            src   => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (input_string, 'AL32UTF8'),
           typ   => encryption_type,
            key   => key_bytes_raw,
            iv    => iv_raw);
            
when lower(Pkey)='d' then
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('encrypted string: ' || encrypted_raw);
    -- The encrypted value "encrypted_raw" can be used here

    decrypted_raw :=
        DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT (src   => input_string,
                             typ   => encryption_type,
                             key   => key_bytes_raw,
                             iv    => iv_raw);
    --Convert RAW to VARCHAR2 in the encoding AL32UTF8.
    output_string := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');
    else output_string:='Invalid Key';
    end case;
return output_string;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Decrypted string: ' || output_string);
    exception when others then return 'Error Denied Key';
    
    
END;
/


this function outputs charachtar with 64 char long so how can i reduce the output length

The output length depends on the input length, among other things. You would need to use a different encryption algorithm that produces a smaller output, and restricting it to always be 16 bytes would perhaps reduce security. Why is 64 bytes a problem?

The table column i used to store the function output is of 24 length and i cannot alter the table

Almost all encryption algorithms are working with blocks, i.e. the output is always a multiple of the block size. Why is it not possible to alter the table?

You won't be able to use that algorithm then. If your input string is up to 15 characters - even a single character - it will encrypt to 32 bytes; 16 chars will be 64 bytes; 32 chars will be 96 etc. Really you need a RAW (not VARCHAR2) column large enough to hold the encrypted version of the longest possible input string.

@AlexPoole do you know different algorithm to use?

Do you want to encrypt or hash the output? If you want to always store 4000 bytes (maximum size of a non-extended VARCHAR2) of input in 16 bytes (characters) then you probably want to hash it - but then you will not be able to decrypt the value as a hash is a one-way function. If you want to store 4000 bytes encrypted and be able to restore it to those 4000 bytes via decryption then you probably cannot store it in 16 bytes as that is mathematically impossible. Either: 1) hash instead of encrypt/decrpyt; 2) encrypt and restrict your input to a small number of bytes; or 3) increase your storage.

@MT0 can i store it in 24 bytes ? i tried different encryption algorithms with padding is set to none the lowest number of bytes i saw is 32 bytes i cannot restrict my input as the input length is fixed always will come in 16 bytes long

How big is your input? If you have 50 bytes of input data then to encrypt it you are going to need at least 50 bytes to store the encrypted value (since any less you will be potentially losing information) but practically you would probably need more as encryption algorithms tend to generate blocks of data so the output would be a multiple of the block size. If you only want to hash the data then the output will be the size the hash function generates (typically 128, 160, 192, 256 or 512 bits - the smaller of those would fit in your space) but you will not be able to decrypt the data.

You could use the Enigma algorithm. There the encrypted text has the same length as the clear text input. For sure you can find a software implementation of it at Github. Regarding security  - well, it's your decision!
